# JCarousel and JqueryUI slider issue

Tags: jquery-plugins

Hi I'm very new to javascript and Jquery. I found the Jcarousel plugin recently and I've tried several of the examples on sorgalla, but can't seem to figure it out.

What i want is to populate the carousel with images(links) from a database, the selection of images i want to display are based on 2 date parameters i get from a jqueryui slider. My idea was to do a ajax request with the "from" and "to" date parameters to a python script which returns the image links in JSON format. But my problem is that when I select a new range of images from the slider the carousel goes bananas(displaying empty boxes or half images).

I would appreciate if someone could nudge me in the right direction here, thanks.
Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function js(){
    $('#mycarousel').empty();
    var start_d=$("#valueAA").val();
    var end_d=$("#valueBB").val();
    $.getJSON("http://www.xxx.com/zzzzzzzzz/cgi-bin/hnf.py"     ,
        {start_d: start_d, end_d: end_d}                                ,
        function(data){
            var encoded = $.toJSON(data);
            for(var i=0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {
                $('#mycarousel').append('<li><img src="' + $.evalJSON(encoded).articles[i].img + '" width="120" height="100" alt="" /></li>');  
            }
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({scroll: 1});
        } 
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $('select#valueAA, select#valueBB').selectToUISlider({
            sliderOptions: { 
                stop: function(e,ui) {
                    js();
                } 
            }
        });
        labels: 12
        //fix color 
        fixToolTipColor();
    });

    //quick function for tooltip color match
    function fixToolTipColor(){
        //grab the bg color from the tooltip content - set top border of pointer to same
        $('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').each(function(){
            var bWidth = $('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').css('borderTopWidth');
            var bColor = $(this).parents('.ui-slider-tooltip').css('backgroundColor')
            $(this).css('border-top', bWidth+' solid '+bColor);
        }); 
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

I can't just empty my ul for some reason, but a fix is to place your ul in a wrapper and destroy that wrapper and remake the ul between each imageset. Probably not the sexiest solution but it works..

solution:

```
function js(){
    $('#wrap').remove();
    $('#container').append('<div id ="wrap"></div>');
    $('#wrap').append('<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"></ul>');
    var start_d=$("#valueAA").val();
    var end_d=$("#valueBB").val();
    $.getJSON("http://www.xxx.com/zzz/cgi-bin/hnf.py"       ,
        {start_d: start_d, end_d: end_d}                                ,
        function(data){
            var encoded = $.toJSON(data);
            for(var i=0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {
                $('#mycarousel').append('<li><img src="' + $.evalJSON(encoded).articles[i].img + '" width="110" height="100" alt="" /></li>');
            }
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({scroll: 1});
        } 
    );
}
```